# Suggested edit approval not earning any reputation

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, reputation

Since yesterday I am seeing an unusual behavior, when ever a suggested edit is [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5469991/piyushj?tab=activity&sort=revisions), I am not seeing any +2 in the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5469991/piyushj?tab=reputation). As far as I know, earlier the criteria for no increment in reputation was 2k, but I am having only 1.4k reputation.

Comment: You have reached the cap. http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation "suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)"

Comment: @MichaelMyers Thanks for the clarification :) But one thing more, the 1000 cap is for over all reputation earned(including the deleted ones)?

Comment: Deletion of posts you edited cause you to lose the 2 reputation you gained. So they don't count against cap.

Comment: @Glorfindel I have a doubt here, If I see my profile, I have still have less than 500 edits approved to be precise its 496, then how can I exhaust my 1000 cap... I guess it takes into account deleted ones as well....or there is some other criteria as well.

Comment: @piyushj The number of posts edited at the top of your profile doesn't count multiple edits to the same post, tag-only edits, and some other criteria. That's not an accurate measure of where you're at regarding the cap. You *have* hit the 1,000 reputation cap for suggested edits and will not continue gaining reputation from them.

Comment: @animuson thanks for the clarification, its now pretty clear.